# Retrieving value from bluetooth BLE device

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

In my windows forms app I am starting to enumerate list of devices as follows:

```
    DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher =
                DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
                        BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false),
                        requestedProperties,
                        DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);
        
    // Register event handlers before starting the watcher.
    // Added, Updated and Removed are required to get all nearby devices
    deviceWatcher.Added += DeviceWatcher_Added;

    // EnumerationCompleted and Stopped are optional to implement.
    deviceWatcher.EnumerationCompleted += DeviceWatcher_EnumerationCompleted;
    deviceWatcher.Stopped += DeviceWatcher_Stopped;

    // Start the watcher.
    deviceWatcher.Start();
```

when a device is found I am retrieving the service and characteristic as follows:

```
    BluetoothLEDevice btdev;
    List<DeviceInformation> lst = new List<DeviceInformation>();
    GattCharacteristic ch;
    private async void DeviceWatcher_Added(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation args)
    {
        if (args.Name == "Bluno")
        {
            btdev = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(args.Id);
            GattDeviceServicesResult result = await btdev.GetGattServicesAsync();
            Guid customGuid = new Guid("0000dfb0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
            foreach (GattDeviceService service in result.Services)
            {
                if (customGuid == service.Uuid)
                {
                    GattCharacteristicsResult cresult = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
                    ch = cresult.Characteristics.Where(x => x.Uuid == new Guid("0000dfb1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")).FirstOrDefault();
                    ch.ValueChanged += Ch_ValueChanged;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the issue is that it is not firing the `ValueChanged` event even if the BLE device continuously sending multiple values per second.
help appreciated

Comment: Have you tried enabling notifications through the client characteristic configuration descriptor?

Comment: `ch.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify)` throws the error `'The attribute cannot be written. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80650003)'`